# Why is python giving me a Syntax error?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code from a tutorial:

```
#File called test
1 def sanitize(time_string):
2         if '-' in time_string:
3                 splitter = '-'
4         elif ':' in time_string:
5                 splitter = ':'
6         else:
7                 return(time_string)
8         (mins, secs) = time_string.split(splitter)
9         return(mins + '.' + secs)
10 
11 
12         
13 def get_coach_data(filename):
14         with open(filename) as f:
15                 data = f.readline()
16         temp1 = data.strip().split(',')
17         return(Athlete(temp1.pop(0), temp1.pop(0), temp1)
18 
19 
20 james = get_coach_data('james2.txt')
21 julie = get_coach_data('julie2.txt')
22 mikey = get_coach_data('mikey2.txt')
23 sarah = get_coach_data('sarah2.txt')
24 
25 print(james.name+"'s fastest times are: " + str(james.top3()))
26 print(juliename+"'s fastest times are: " + str(julie.top3())) 
27 print(mikey.name+"'s fastest times are: " + str(mikey.top3()))
28 print(sarah.name+"'s fastest times are: " + str(sarah.top3()))
```

and I put this class separately because I thought it may have been causing the error:

```
 1 class Athlete:
 2         def __init__(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_times=[]):
 3                 self.name = a_name
 4                 self.dob = a_dob
 5                 self.times = a_times
 6 
 7         def top3(self):
 8                 return(sorted(set([sanitize(t) for t in self.times]))[0:3])
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "test.py", line 20
james = get_coach_data('james2.txt')
```

But the error doesn't make any sense. I am new to python. I appreciate anyones help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors that I can see are:

1. ```
   return(Athlete(temp1.pop(0), temp1.pop(0), temp1)
   ```

   in `get_coach_data` should just be

   ```
   return Athlete(temp1.pop(0), temp1.pop(0), temp1)
   ```

   on line 17
2. `juliename` should be `julie.name` on line 26

Comment: a_times=[] in an `__init__` is also a bad idea (there's only one default list shared by all instances, made when the function is defined, not each time `Athlete.__init__` is called.)

Comment: This indentation in python is really annoying. Thanks, I appreciate it. I swear I corrected any erroneous parens. I am confused why the error would happen there but not in the actual function. Is there a reason?